# Linq List Contains Method

Tags: c#, linq

Im newbie to linq and im using linq query to retrieve data from the table.My idea is to list all the cashsafes corresponding to a particular user and show it in dropdownlist.

The table structure is shown below

```
Table 1
cashsafeid  cashsafename
  1           cashsafe1
  2           cashsafe2
  3           cashsafe3

Table 2
 Id   UserId   Cashsafeid 
  1    100      1,2,3
  2    101      1,3
```

I've to get the cashsafename of a particular user say 100.How can i achieve it
The below code is the one i've tried but am stuck

```
 List<Cashsafe> cashsafes=(from c in db.Table 1
                              where c.CashsafeId contains() )--Cannot go further
```

Comment: I think you need to fix first your tables, for you to be able to get what you desired.

Comment: You should really reconsider your database design. Try (and in this case, definitely try) to avoid comma-separated columns. Try normalizing some more.

Comment: I recommend that you create another table that will map the relation between your two table. since the relationship of your table is 1 to many, each row will contain 1 userdid and 1 cashsafeid. doing so will make it easier for you to join your tables.

Answer (score 4):

You store User's Cachsafeid column in very inefficient way - it doesn't allow to generate efficient SQL for LINQ provider. So the following solution has bad performance - if you care about that - change your table structure.

```
var user = db.Table2.Single(u => u.UserId == 100);
var cachfeIds = user.Cashsafeid.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
var cachefes = db.Table1.Where(c => cachfeIds.Contains(c.Id)).ToList();
```

Basically you need to join to tables, but foreign key is "virtual" - it is only in your mind. To retrieve foreign key values we must split the Cachsafeid column's value of every user to retrieve linked cachefes. And only then retrieve the cachefes with separate request (I think LINQ will retrieve all values from table and the execute Where part in C# code).

Comment: More precisely, the OP needs to formulate a condition after the `where`, where currently only a member is dereferenced.

Comment: Please read the question carefully i've two tables and i want to list all the cashsafename(Table1) belonging to a particular user(Table2)

Comment: @SparAby, thanks, I already realized I was wrong. Fixed answer

Comment: I agree to @GrantWinney

Comment: Fixed answer once more. Sorry for posting untested solutions - I don't have your Db entities. Now tested with Linq to objects. Should work.

Answer (score 0):

if you have no idea of join you can use

```
 int x = 0;
                List<int> Users = db.table2.FirstOrDefault(m => m.UserId == 100).Cashsafeid.Split(',').ToList().Where(str => int.TryParse(str, out x)).Select(str => x).ToList(); ;
                var content = db.table1.Where(m => Users.Contains(m.cashsafeid)).ToList();
```

Comment: Here im getting a message that you cannot convert string to int in the first linq query

Comment: Maybe it's working, but it is so awfully unobvious! You can drop the TryParse part - it's unlikely that in his DB values are not numbers, and if they are, we shouldn't just silently work with corrupted data. It may lead to even worse data corruption

Comment: Sure its working.  conditions provided by you is in int.